# Envío de formularios ya cancelados

Tags: javascript, json, formularios

Uso un form-popup de Bootstrap , es decir, el formulario se despliega a hacer click para un nuevo post o editar uno existente. El envío se hace mediante un fetch. El problema es que si cancelo el o varios envío/s sin recargar la página, en el envío confirmado se envían también los datos cancelados anteriormente. He intentado con reset() y AbortController() pero nada funciona salvo location.reload(). Alguna forma de cancelar el envío del formulario sin tener que recargar la página?

Lo que sigue es el mismo texto debido a que me dice que la pregunta es muy concisa.

*Uso un form-popup de Bootstrap , es decir, el formulario se despliega a hacer click para un nuevo post o editar uno existente. El envío se hace mediante un fetch. El problema es que si cancelo el o varios envío/s sin recargar la página, en el envío confirmado se envían también los datos cancelados anteriormente. He intentado con reset() y AbortController() pero nada funciona salvo location.reload(). Alguna forma de cancelar el envío del formulario sin tener que recargar la página?
Uso un form-popup de Bootstrap , es decir, el formulario se despliega a hacer click para un nuevo post o editar uno existente. El envío se hace mediante un fetch. El problema es que si cancelo el o varios envío/s sin recargar la página, en el envío confirmado se envían también los datos cancelados anteriormente. He intentado con reset() y AbortController() pero nada funciona salvo location.reload(). Alguna forma de cancelar el envío del formulario sin tener que recargar la página?*

```
<!-- Formulario desplegable -->
<button class="open-button" onclick="new_post()">New 
            <br> post</button>
        
        <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
            <form action="#" id="my-form" class="form-container">
                <div>
                    <h3 id="post-title"></h3>   
                </div>
                <div>      
                    <textarea id="post" class="post-text" placeholder="" name="post" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="form-buttons">                
                    <button type="submit" id="send" class="post-btn" title="Send">
                        <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" id="close" class="post-btn cancel" title="Close" onclick="closeForm()">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>



// new_post() se llama desde el botón del formulario, 
// edit_post() se llama desde un ícono manejado por el sig, código

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const elem = event.target;
    if (elem.className.includes('edit-event')){
        const body = event.path[4].children[1].innerHTML;
        const post_id = event.path[4].children[1].id;
        edit_post(body, post_id);
    }    
});


// envio del nuevo post
function new_post() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("post-title").innerHTML = 'New Post';
    document.getElementById("post").focus();
    document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', () =>{        
        const body = document.querySelector('#post').value;
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/new_post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                body
            })
        })
        .then(response =>  response.json())  
        .then(result => {
            const resultKey = Object.keys(result)
            if (resultKey == 'error') {
            window.alert(result['error']);
            }
        })
    })   
}

// edición de un post
function edit_post(body='', post_id) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("post-title").innerHTML = 'Edit Post';
    document.getElementById("post").focus();
    document.querySelector('#post').value = body;
    document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', () =>{     
        const upBody = document.querySelector('#post').value;
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/edit_post', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'crossorigin': 'anonymous',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                upBody,
                post_id
            })
        })
        .then(response =>  response.json())  
        .then(result => {
            const resultKey = Object.keys(result)
            if (resultKey == 'error') {
            window.alert(result['error']);
            }
        }) 
    })  
}

// cierre del formulario y cancelación de envío usando location.reload()
function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revise el código y lo primero que detecte es que añades el addEventListener cada que le das clic al botón de nuevo post o al de editar post, pero nunca quitas el evento, tu estarás añadiendo un nuevo evento a tu evento clic, tantas veces como des clic al boton, y será las mismas numero de veces que se ejecutara tu función y te enviara esas mismas peticiones.

Supongo esa es la razón por la que al cancelar y de nuevo intentar, te vuelve a reenviar la petición.

Otra cosa que note es que deberías de tener un evento que genere un borrado de tu form, cada que cierres o vuelvas a abrir el form, así no conservas información anterior.

Te dejo el codigo con el que yo trabajaria, en este caso en new_post y en edit_post, quito el evento onclic de los dos posibles listeners que tenga (no genera error si no tienes ninguno asignado), y posterior asigno un evento segun sea el caso.

Las funciones las separe, para poder generar el removeListener (Tienes que pasar la función que quieres remover) [documentación removeListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) .

Dado que necesitas enviar el parámetro post en tu evento fetch, genere una variable global, la cual le asigno el valor cuando le des clic al evento edit_post.

Y agregue una función clearForm, para borrar el contenido de el campo o campos cuando muestras el form.

```js
var postid = 0;

// envio del nuevo post
function new_post() {
  clearform();
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("post-title").innerHTML = "New Post";
  document.getElementById("post").focus();
  document.querySelector("#send").removeEventListener("click", sendNewPost);
  document.querySelector("#send").removeEventListener("click", sendEditPost);

  document.querySelector("#send").addEventListener("click", sendNewPost);
}

function sendNewPost(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const body = document.querySelector("#post").value;
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/new_post", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      crossorigin: "anonymous"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      body
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      closeForm();
      const resultKey = Object.keys(result);
      if (resultKey == "error") {
        window.alert(result["error"]);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => { //Este evento lo agregue para poder cerrar el form cuando no responde la petición.
      //Como ahorita que se cancela por que no encuentra la ruta
      closeForm();
    });
}
function sendEditPost(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const upBody = document.querySelector("#post").value;
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/edit_post", {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      crossorigin: "anonymous",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      upBody,
      postid
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      closeForm();
      const resultKey = Object.keys(result);
      if (resultKey === "error") {
        window.alert(result["error"]);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {//Este evento lo agregue para poder cerrar el form cuando no responde la petición.
      //Como ahorita que se cancela por que no encuentra la ruta
      closeForm();
    });
}

// edición de un post
function edit_post(body = "", post_id) {
  clearform();
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("post-title").innerHTML = "Edit Post";
  document.getElementById("post").focus();
  document.querySelector("#post").value = body;
  postid = post_id;

  document.querySelector("#send").removeEventListener("click", sendNewPost);
  document.querySelector("#send").removeEventListener("click", sendEditPost);

  document.querySelector("#send").addEventListener("click", sendEditPost);
}

// cierre del formulario y cancelación de envío usando location.reload()
function closeForm() {
  postid = 0;
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
  clearform();
  // location.reload();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  closeForm();
});

function clearform() {
  document.querySelector("#post").value = "";
}
```

```html
<!-- Formulario desplegable -->
    <button class="open-button" onclick="new_post()">
      New <br />
      post
    </button>
    <button class="open-button" onclick="edit_post('hola' , 1)">
      Edit <br />
      post
    </button>

    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
      <form action="#" id="my-form" class="form-container">
        <div>
          <h3 id="post-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            id="post"
            class="post-text"
            placeholder=""
            name="post"
            required
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="form-buttons">
          <button type="submit" id="send" class="post-btn" title="Send">
            <i class="fas fa-share"></i>Enviar
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            id="close"
            class="post-btn cancel"
            title="Close"
            onclick="closeForm()"
          >
            Cancelar
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: En primer lugar Eduardo, muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y compartir tus conocimientos. Implementé el código con apenas unos cambios para que se acomodara al resto de la estructura y funciona de maravilla. En algún momento había intentado también usar removeEventListener() pero no funcionó ya que, obviamente, no lo hice con tu destreza (a partir de la segunda apertura del formulario para editar ya no me aparecía el texto original) y terminé por abandonar ese camino, que resultó ser el correcto. De nuevo, gracias y un saludo cordial.